# Confused about F# method signature syntax

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am supposed to write a small program in F# for a uni assignment. One of the exercises says to create a filter method with this signature:
`filter : ('a -> bool) -> list<'a> -> list<'a>`. But I am struggling to properly interpret this syntax. The docs say the syntax for creating a method is
`let [inline] function-name parameter-list [ : return-type ] = function-body`. But how does my example fit into this? Is it a function which takes no parameters but returns three values?

The function should filter a list given a predicate which is simple enough, but if it doesn't take any parameters, how should I pass a predicate and list? I am sure I'm missing something major because I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Nice to hear that a university teaches some F#. What university and/or course is this? Just curious.

Comment: @Abel It's a functional programming course at the Technical University of Applied Sciences in Vienna.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you may be referring to tells you how to *implement* a function. The signature you've been given, however, is the desired function's *type*. F# types are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-types

Specifically, the documentation says that in its simplest form, a function has the type `parameter-type1 -> return-type`, but when it has more parameters, it generally takes the form `parameter-type1 -> parameter-type2 -> ... -> return-type`.

In F#, functions are values, so the desired `filter` is a *value* that happens to be a function. The function should take two inputs: `('a -> bool)` and `list<'a>`, and return a value of the type `list<'a>`.

One of the inputs is a function in its own right: `('a -> bool)`.

Comment: Just as an example, a function `('a -> bool)` could look like `fun f x = if x > 42 then true else false`. Then, let's say your filter function is called `filter`, you would call it as `filter f myList`. Here, `f` fits the first argument that is `('a -> bool)`. Inside the _implementation_ of `filter` you can use that argument just as if it is any other function.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is saying that `filter` is a function which takes a predicate function of type `'a -> bool` and returns a function which takes a `list<'a>` and returns another value of type `list<'a>`.

This is because functions only transform one value into another, but either of those values *can be a function*.

As a practical matter, `filter` takes two arguments: that predicate function which take one `'a` value and returns a boolean, and a `list<'a>`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question is that that function takes two arguments and returns a value:

```
('a -> bool) // arg 1
-> list<'a> // arg 2
-> list<'a> // return value
```

In F#, function arguments can also be thought of as part of the return value because of partially applied functions e.g. you can think of the above as "given the first arg, return back a new function that expects the second arg and gives back the filtered list".

```
('a -> bool) // arg
-> (list<'a> -> list<'a>) // return value
```